# Change StringFormat during Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, string-formatting, datagridtextcolumn

I have the following Scenario where I want to change the `StringFormat` of a `DataGridTextColumn` on runtime. On my `DataGrid` I have also a `DataGridTemplate` with a `Button` inside. When I press the `Button` I want to change the `StringFormat` from two decimal places to zero decimal places. How can I do that? I have already tried working with `Styles` and `Dynamic Resources` but nothing is working so far. This Code happens in my `AutogenerateColumns`-Event. DGC is the current column.

```
DataTrigger t = new DataTrigger();
                        t.Binding = new Binding("Weight");
                        t.Value = 0;
                        Setter s = new Setter();
                        s.Property = DataGridCell.ContentStringFormatProperty;
                        s.Value = new Binding(null) { StringFormat = "N02" };
                        t.Setters.Add(s);

                        Sty.Triggers.Add(t);
                        DGC.CellStyle = Sty;
```

Comment: What is the name of the property at wpf ? Did you try to give a name to that datagrid?

Comment: When the `Button` is pressed it changes a Value in the `DataTable` that is the Source of the `DataGrid`, in the Column Weight, to 0 or 1

Comment: You can define DataTemplate object inside your DataGrid and give a name inside datatemplate object like TextBlock. and if you give a name to that textblock at clickEvent Handler you can access that ui element and set its attribute there. (This is not a good idea for wpf logic but would be useful I think)